# handling matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have data like this

```
    SB1 SB2 SB3 DB1 DB2 DB3 DB4 DB5 FB1 FB2 FB3 FB4
SB1 ... -45 32  -4  10  -13 -9  12  -45 -4  -43 -2
SB2 45  ... 30  70  55  60  16  20  22  48  0   8
SB3 -32 -30 ... -26 -40 -10 -14 31  -10 -82 -97 -4
DB1 4   -70 26  ... -5  2   7   32  -4  0   -45 0
DB2 -10 -55 40  5   ... 2   3   26  -43 0   -43 0
DB3 13  -60 10  -2  -2  ... -3  29  20  -4  -6  0
DB4 9   -16 14  -7  -3  3   ... 20  19  -30 -8  0
DB5 -12 -20 -31 -32 -26 -29 -20 ... 0   -20 -23 -20
FB1 45  -22 10  4   43  -20 -19 0   ... -20 -20 -20
FB2 4   -48 82  0   0   4   30  20  20  ... 0   0
FB3 43  0   97  45  43  6   8   23  20  0   ... 0
FB4 2   -8  4   0   0   0   0   20  20  0   0   ...
```

What I want is to remove the negative number from this matrix and it can be done with this command:

```
 apply(inter,2, function (x){ifelse(x<0,0,x)})
```

However, this code remove both the negative and the "..." which I need for further calculation. How can i remove the negative but still preserve the "..."? I have tried this code

```
apply(inter1,2, function (x){ifelse(x>0|x %in% "...",x,0)})
```

but it doesn't work and R gave me this warning

```
Error in apply(inter1, 2, function(x) { : 
dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Please give me some advice and if you could, please let me know which package is the best in handing data in matrix form.

Thank you.

Comment: Is `...` a character string, or are these `NA` values? Is `inter` a matrix or a data frame?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Is this an object of class data.frame? Because then every column will only be of only one atomic type, meaning every element of your matrix is of type character due to the "...".
2. If you actually want to do calculations, why the dots? You can not use them in a meaningful way in a mathematical function. Your function works only because the ">" operator compares the alphabetical value if the letters. The dots get removed because their alphabetical value is higher than zero in R.
3. Lastly, the apply() function with argument MARGIN=2 uses the complete column as input for the applied function, while what you want to do is to apply a function to every single element. A lot of R functions are vectorized, but the function that you would need has to be written with this in mind.

If you actually want the dots to stay as is, you will have to do a check for them first. Here's a way to do this:

```
checkerFun <- function(x){
    if(x=="...") return("...") else {
        x <- as.integer(x)
        x <- ifelse(x>0,0,x)
        return(x)
    }
}

data.frame(lapply(X=inter, FUN=function(x){sapply(X=x,checkerFun)}))
```

Explanation: checkerFun() first compares the element to the dots, if the element is anything else it coerces it into an integer and applies your replacement. checkerFun is a function which expects a single element as input, not a vector like it would get as input in an *apply type function.
In the last row, i nest an sapply in an lapply: the lapply runs the function on every element of inter, which is a list of atomic vectors. Therefore, the FUN argument of lapply() needs to be another sapply() function, which runs checkerFun on every element of each of the given vectors.

Comment: Since this is marked as the correct answer, I'd suggest you would fix a few of the inaccuracies here. First, `>` does not coerce strings to integers; it will compare using alphabetical order. Check out `"abc" > "def"` and `"abc" < "def"`. Second, `apply` with margin 2 works on columns, not rows.

Comment: done, thanks for the input and sorry for the late response, i don't check this account very often.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is currently stored as text because of the "..." values. You'll probably find it easier to store these special values as `NA` and to store your data in a numeric matrix:

```
# Load data, currently stored as a data frame with text in it
dat <- read.table(text="    SB1 SB2 SB3 DB1 DB2 DB3 DB4 DB5 FB1 FB2 FB3 FB4
SB1 ... -45 32  -4  10  -13 -9  12  -45 -4  -43 -2
SB2 45  ... 30  70  55  60  16  20  22  48  0   8
SB3 -32 -30 ... -26 -40 -10 -14 31  -10 -82 -97 -4
DB1 4   -70 26  ... -5  2   7   32  -4  0   -45 0
DB2 -10 -55 40  5   ... 2   3   26  -43 0   -43 0
DB3 13  -60 10  -2  -2  ... -3  29  20  -4  -6  0
DB4 9   -16 14  -7  -3  3   ... 20  19  -30 -8  0
DB5 -12 -20 -31 -32 -26 -29 -20 ... 0   -20 -23 -20
FB1 45  -22 10  4   43  -20 -19 0   ... -20 -20 -20
FB2 4   -48 82  0   0   4   30  20  20  ... 0   0
FB3 43  0   97  45  43  6   8   23  20  0   ... 0
FB4 2   -8  4   0   0   0   0   20  20  0   0   ...", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Convert to a numeric matrix, with `NA` instead of ...
mat <- data.matrix(dat)
```

Now, you should find it relatively simple to replace all the negative values with 0:

```
mat[mat < 0] <- 0
mat
#     SB1 SB2 SB3 DB1 DB2 DB3 DB4 DB5 FB1 FB2 FB3 FB4
# SB1  NA   0  32   0  10   0   0  12   0   0   0   0
# SB2  45  NA  30  70  55  60  16  20  22  48   0   8
# SB3   0   0  NA   0   0   0   0  31   0   0   0   0
# DB1   4   0  26  NA   0   2   7  32   0   0   0   0
# DB2   0   0  40   5  NA   2   3  26   0   0   0   0
# DB3  13   0  10   0   0  NA   0  29  20   0   0   0
# DB4   9   0  14   0   0   3  NA  20  19   0   0   0
# DB5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  NA   0   0   0   0
# FB1  45   0  10   4  43   0   0   0  NA   0   0   0
# FB2   4   0  82   0   0   4  30  20  20  NA   0   0
# FB3  43   0  97  45  43   6   8  23  20   0  NA   0
# FB4   2   0   4   0   0   0   0  20  20   0   0  NA
```

Instead of using `x == "..."` to check for your special values, you can use `is.na(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to convert `...` to `NA`.  If your data is `matrix`, I assume the columns are `character` class.  If you don't want `...` to get converted to NA and wants the matrix to remain `character` class

```
indx1 <- grep("\\d+", inter)  #inter is the matrix
inter[indx1][as.numeric(inter[indx1]) <0] <- 0
inter
```